# Convert 5 digit date in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, julian-date

I have an Oracle database table with 5 digit Julian dates that I need to convert to date time format.

Sample data

```
Source  Actual date
40786 ->    2015-09-01 |
40785 ->    2015-08-31 |
```

First I tried the following

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(to_char(40786), 'J'),'DD-MM-YYYY'),
       to_char(to_date(to_char(40785), 'J'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
  FROM dual; 

40786 ->    4601-09-01 |
40785 ->    4601-08-31 |
```

Since it is wrong I calculated the difference in days (2416481) and formulated the following query

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(to_char(40786 + 2416481  ), 'J'),'DD-MM-YYYY'),
       to_char(to_date(to_char(40785 + 2416481), 'J'),'DD-MM-YYYY')  
  FROM dual; 

40786 ->    2015-09-01 |
40785 ->    2015-08-31 |
```

It is correct for above two days but the table has a history since 2010. Will the above adjustment hold correct for the full history. i.e. weekends, leap years etc ...

Many thanks.
V

Comment: If the source data is wrong to begin with, what confidence do you have that it will be *consistently* wrong for all the other records?  And by *consistently*, I mean, how do you know that all the other records will have the exact same day offset (2416481)?  I would have a hard look at why the dates are wrong in the first place, and make sure it's not just a misinterpretation of your source data.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick reply. Let me clarify. The source data has been used by a system and been verified over time. So the data is correct. But I don't know the conversion method they used. (There is a GUI that displays the correct format) My guess was the dates are offset by 2416481 days because it seemed to work correctly for the recent days. If you find a collection of dates in Julian format and only can cross check the last few days, would you offset all the dates by the offset derived using the know dates or is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the column is **not** stored in Julian date. So you can't ask if the conversion will work or not.
It seems that the dates are based on 1.1.1904 (=  day zero)

So the conversion is as follows:

```
 select to_date('1904-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + 40786 as dt from dual;

 DT
 ---------- 
 01.09.2015

 select to_date('1904-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + 40785 as dt from dual;

 DT
 ---------- 
 31.08.2015
```

If it will realy work, can answer only the code in your GUI conversion routine.

And yes, if you trust in rational software development, you could expect it will work (for dates say in  +/- 100 years range).

Comment: I seem to recall that 1904 was sometimes used in Excel to avoid confusion over whether 1900 was a leap year, but there are potential issues switching between them. So I guess obvious follow-on questions for the OP are where the data came from, and if the source was always based on 1904 and not 1900. (ha, [should have searched before commenting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/180162))

Comment: Thanks v much. This makes more sense. I think this is the solution.

Comment: Good observation @Alex ; I was first confused not to find the year 1900. It make sense!